# How to store users data in external database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership

I've created database wih Application Services objects as described on [official website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs). But when I want to add new user ( using `Membership.AddUSer(...)`) default local ASPNETDB.mdf database is created and user data is stored there. I've added connection string to webconfig file and configured database as shown in mentioned tutorial, but it's still not working. Where I can configure membership provider to store data in my production database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at membership section in web.config and set parameter connectionStringName for AspNetSqlMembershipProvider to name of your connection string name.

Comment: By default I didnt had membership section in my webconfig, thats the source of my confusion. Your response clue me in on full solution described on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx